# Can I change the root path to execute a cron task?

Tags: shell, cron

I got a shell script( a toy-example one here):

it creates a file on current directory:

```
#! /usr/bin/sh
touch ./toy
touch ./doll
touch ./boy
touch ./kuky
touch ./beer
```

This shell is put on a deep path: `/somewhere/which/is/in/a/huge/path/tree/maze`

But when I use crontab to execute that shell script, with no doubt it will create these files under `~/`.

So this means if I want to create these files on `/somewhere/which/is/in/a/huge/path/tree/maze`, I have to add this long path after every touch command. In this case five long path. Disaster for reading.

But if I can change the root file where I execute this shell, I'll need only one such path in the script or crontab.

Is there a way to do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change directory:

```
#!/bin/sh
cd /somewhere/which/is/in/a/huge/path/tree/maze
...
```

Or use a variable:

```
dir="/somewhere/which/is/in/a/huge/path/tree/maze"
touch "$dir/toy"
...
```

Comment: Great solutions, I think my brain stuck here, didn't let `cd` comes to my mind.

Answer (score 0):

In my crontab of debian I have this entry :

```
17 * * * * root cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly
```

Do I need to tell more ?